# Null Pointer in LibGDX Splash screen

Tags: android, libgdx, splash-screen

I have a splash class which should simply show a splash image and yet it causes a null pointer exception. Its agitating as I have made other Java applications in where this method had worked. I have read a great deal of documentation to see where I was going wrong but I can't seem to find it.

```
Splash.java class
package com.me.fypapplication;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Splash implements Screen{

private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
private Texture splashTexture;
private Sprite sprite;

private Game myGame;

private OrthographicCamera camera;

public Splash (Game g)
{
    myGame = g;
}

public void create() {

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(800,400);

    splashTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/splashtest.gif"));

    sprite = new Sprite(splashTexture);
    sprite.setSize(512, 512);
    sprite.setPosition(256, 256);

    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

    splashTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);


}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    spriteBatch.begin();
    sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();

}
```

If anyone could help will be much appreciated!

EDIT! 
Forgot the error

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.me.fypapplication.Splash.render(Splash.java:51)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:190)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your camera is null because nothing is calling *create()*. If you're implementing a libgdx Screen and need to initialise things then you should override the *show()* method before *render()* is called.